# how to configure nutch 1.8 in windows error: nutch : command not found

Tags: apache, nutch

I am trying to configure nutch in windows 7 and i have followed the follwing steps

I have download and unziped the apache nutch 1.8,
I have specified the agent name in  conf/nutch-site.xml like

```
<configuration>
<property>
 <name>http.agent.name</name>
 <value>My Nutch Spider</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

and in apache home follwing command i did ->

mkdir -p urls

cd urls

touch seed.txt      --> to create a text file seed.txt under urls/ with the following content  (one URL per line for each site you want Nutch to crawl).

nutch.apache.org/

in conf/regex-urlfilter.txt edit with--> +^([a-z0-9]*.)*nutch.apache.org/

but in bin when i am doing

bin/nutch crawl urls -dir crawl -depth 3 -topN 5

error occurred -> bash: nutch: command not found

why ?

Answer (score 0):

Nutch scripts are written for linux environments.

You might use this (although it seems it needs a lot more work to be completed):

https://github.com/veggen/nutch-windows-script

Or setup Cygwin as suggested here:

http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/GettingNutchRunningWithWindows